# XMPP Chat issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

I have two users registered in my app. Let us say user1 and user2. When user1 and user2 are online, chat is working properly. Now when user 1 is online and user2 is offline & I am trying to send message from user 1 to user 2. In this case chat is not working. But as soon as the user2 is online, the message is send from user1 and received at user 2.

Note - sending message to server, is not working when the other user is offline.

Can anybody guide me?

Comment: Well, if the contact to which you try to send the message is offline (not connected) then it won't receive the message (because there is no connection to send the message over). In case of iOS you have to use "push", which will notify not connected users that there are messages.

Comment: I was just pondering it some more - do you mean that all messages sent while `user2` was offline were not delivered (even when `user2` connected)? In general XMPP server should store those in 'offline store' and once user2 connects, xmpp server should send them back to user2.

Comment: I understand the push notification thing. But I need to understand why the message is not received at server and if it is received at server where can I find it in app code XMPP delegates ?

Comment: I have written this code      
   
if([message elementForName:@"server_receipt"] != nil
           && [[[message elementForName:@"server_receipt"] stringValue] isEqualToString:@"server_receipt_atklique"]){
            NSLog(@"************* Message reached to server ************");

Where should I write this code?